# Pass values through forms with in a safe way

Tags: vb6

I'm using this "method" to pass values through forms:

`Form1`

```
Public iCodName    As Long
```

Then on `Form2`

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()
   Form1.iCodName = 10
End Sub
```

I know it is `NOT` a safe way to do this, because all my variables must be `GLOBAL` to do this, so I'd like to ask a safe way to pass these kind of values through forms or a best way to do so if this is not a `Good Practice` of programming.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that, it's not unsafe as far as I'm aware. What do you suspect is wrong with this approach?

Comment: @DeeMac Really? So I'm allowed to do this as I Wish? I thought it was unsafe by the fact that I have GLOBAL variables and it could be to be accessed somehow to harm the system... And is it a `bad practice`?

Comment: Well 'good practice' is extremely dependent upon what it is, exactly, you're trying to do. If you want a variable globally accessible to all that can access it, it's fine. If you want to modify the access to this variable to a certain extent then you'll need to consider a different approach. What is the variable used for? Provide more context.

Comment: @DeeMac I have a QueryString, a string with a query as it's value, ok?
So I need to pass the value of some string From `Form1` TO `Form2`.
And use the value of this string in Form2. But I'll use these only between these two forms... `Form1` has a button that opens `Form2` and I need to pass this value. It will be used only between these two forms.

Comment: `iCodName` could be wrapped in a property getter/setter to avoid Public but it is functionally not much different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your form:

```
Dim iCodName    As Long
' private???  I forget, my VB6 is rusty...
Public Property Get CodeName() As Long
    Return iCodName    
End Property

Public Property Let CodeName(ByVal vNewValue As Long)
  iCodName    = vNewValue
End Property
```

It is not a lot different than a bare public member, but does prevent iCodName from being Public

Comment: I'm used to work with C#, and in C# there is a big difference between public and `Get\Set` method when comes to security... SO with vb6 there not such concern?

Comment: the main difference is that other code cant ACCIDENTALLY change it: `iCodName = -1`, it would have to deliberate: `frmName.CodeName = -1` but otherwise anything can change it because it is public.

Comment: Only things declared Public in a static module get put into the global namespace.  This "accident" simply can't occur.

Comment: @Bob77 I knew that was true in .NET, could not recall VB6 - thanks.

Comment: "It is not a lot different than a bare public member". It's not at all different than a bare public member except that it's more complicated.

Comment: @Boann but it DOES allow the "owner" of the variable to examine and qualify it in the setter which the other way does not.  It has it's value but more so over a Public var in a module.